# Colocar os ícones do Font Awesome dentro das listas ordenadas no menu

Tags: css, font-awesome

Colegas.

Tenho um menu em Bootstrap do qual gostaria de colocar os ícones do Font Awesome ao lado de cada item desse menu. O HTML está dessa forma:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">                          
    <li><a href="#">Todos os nomes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome E</a></li>
</ul>
```

O CSS do **dropdown-menu** está assim:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
```

Ao acessar o site oficial do Font Awesome, encontrei uma classe nativa deles **fa-ul** e o **fa-li**, então coloquei dessa forma:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu fa-ul">                          
    <li><a href="#">Todos os nomes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i> Nome A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nome E</a></li>
</ul>
```

O ícone apareceu, mas estourou pelo nosso lado esquerdo. Veja ao lado do **Nome A**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faria para corrigir?

Comment: coloca as `li`'s em `position:relative;` os `i`'s dentro de `li`'s como `absolute`, e posicione-os como quiser ;)

Comment: Olá Murilo. Perdoe-me a ignorância, mas não consegui entender direito. Poderia me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: `ul li {position:relative;}` e, `li i{position:absolute;}`, não é ignorância alguma man ;D se n funcionar e voc puder compartilhar o código completo, pelo team viewer posso estar ajudando

Comment: Obrigado Murilo. Funcionou.

Comment: coloca sua resposta e dentro de 2 dias já da como a certa ;)

Comment: Murilo, não deixe de postar como resposta, senão a página fica "manca"... como já foi respondida nos comentários, ninguém vai colocar resposta para um problema que vc solucionou, e daí acaba ficando 'respondida' mas sem resposta...

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira caso utilize Font Awesome seria inserido a tag do ícone que deseja dentro de cada elemento

. Outra maneira é inserindo via css através do :before do elemento consultado o código content em css que representa cada ícone por exemplo "content: '/cf434'" mas é um ruim para manutenção futura.

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/796628eb4f.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">                          
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i> Todos os nomes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nome A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nome B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nome C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nome D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nome E</a></li>
</ul>
```